# Does a linear function $\mathrm {End}_K(V) \otimes \mathrm {End}_K(V) \to \mathrm {End}_K(V)$ which maps $A \otimes B$ to $A \circ B$ exist?

Tags: linear-algebra, tensor-products

$K$ is a field and $V$ a finite dimensional $K$-vector space.

Does a linear function $\mathrm {End}_K(V) \otimes \mathrm {End}_K(V) \to \mathrm {End}_K(V)$ which maps $A \otimes B$ to $A \circ B$, for all $A,B \in \mathrm {End}_K(V)$ exist?

Comment: As in your other recent questions, "think bilinear".

Comment: The question you're really asking is does composition of endomorphisms distribute over addition of functions. The answer is yes.

Comment: Think about the $\text{universal property}$ of tensor product. There exist a linear map in your question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on the fact that you have asked several questions that have essentially the same answer, it seems that what you really need is an explanation of the [universal property](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor_product#Universal_property) that characterizes tensor products.  In particular:

> For any vector spaces $V,W,Z$ and any bilinear map $h: V \times W \to Z$, there exists a unique linear map $\phi: V \otimes W \to Z$ that satisfies $\phi(v \otimes w) = h(v,w)$.

In your case, we have $h:\operatorname{End}(V)\times \operatorname{End}(V) \to \operatorname{End}(V)$ defined by $h(A,B) = A \circ B$. This is a **bilinear** map, which is to say that we have
$$
h(c_1 A_1 + c_2A_2,B) = c_1h(A_1,B) + c_2h(A_2,B)\\
h(A,c_1 B_1 + c_2B_2) = c_1h(A,B_1) + c_2h(A,B_2)
$$
for all $A,B \in \operatorname{End}(V)$ and $c_1,c_2 \in K$. It follows that there is a unique linear map $\phi: \operatorname{End}(V)\otimes \operatorname{End}(V) \to \operatorname{End}(V)$ for which $\phi(A \otimes B) = A \circ B$.

Comment: Just to be sure, the universal property holds provided the vector spaces are finite dimensional (or it holds in greater generality)?

Comment: @lcv It holds in greater generality. It holds in any instance where the tensor product is used in abstract algebra, including the tensor product of modules over possibly non-commutative rings (though the definition of "bilinear" gets tricky in the non-commutative setting).

Comment: Thank you, very interesting